# Get attributes of element that is already hovered over on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<tr>` element with a `data-id` attribute. When hovering over a `<td>` within the row, then holding down `ctrl`, I would like to get the `data-id` from the `<tr>` and change the background color.

I want this event to be fired when the user holds down `ctrl` and is already hovering over a `<td>` in the `<tr>`, however I can not figure out a method that works.

This works if the user holds down control THEN hovers over the `<td>`:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            var row = $(this).parent();
            var id = row.data("id");
            row.addClass("danger");
            //AJAX request with id
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var row = $(this).parent();
        row.removeClass("danger");
    }
}, ".sigData");
```

I have tried using the following plugin to check to see if the mouse is hovered over the `<tr>` when `ctrl` is clicked:

```
    (function ($) {
    $.fn.isMouseOver = function () {
        return $(this).parent().find($(this).selector + ":hover").length > 0;
    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if ($('.sigData').isMouseOver()) {
        var id = $(this).parent().data("id");
        $(this).parent().addClass("danger");
        //AJAX request with id
    }
})
```

The `<tr>` is added dynamically with JavaScript from an AJAX request when opening up a Bootstrap modal.
Example output:

```
<tr data-id="8">
    <td class="sigData"><span rel="tooltip" title="John Doe">1275302</span></td>
    <td class="sigData">11/26/2015</td>
    <td class="sigData">Yes</td>
</tr>
```

#### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yvr0bdt0/6/)

### EDIT 1 (11/29)

For some reason I thought that `$.addClass()` took speed as a parameter. Removed. 
For clarification, the `$(this).parent().data("id")` is used for an AJAX request. Updated.

The JSFiddle example has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember the last entered row a variable to have a reference when handling the `CTRL` key down event afterwards. When leaving the row, you should unset the reference.

My example makes use of [`toggleClass(classnames, state)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to avoid an verbose `if`-`else` statement.

```
// will be set on mouseenter, unset on mouseleave
// (can be used in subsequent keyevent)
var lastRow = null;
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        var row = $(this).parent();
        var id = row.data("id");

        // remember row for later key event
        lastRow = row;

        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            row.addClass("danger");
        }

        // AJAX request with id
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        lastRow.removeClass("danger");
        // unset the reference, since we're leaving the cell (and thus potentially changing the row)
        lastRow = null;
    }
}, ".sigData");

$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (!lastRow || !e.ctrlKey) {
        // no row hovered recently or no CTRL key pressed
        return;
    }

    lastRow.toggleClass("danger", e.ctrlKey);

    var id = lastRow.data("id");
    //AJAX request with id
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgaqgs85/1/) (kindly provided by bnahin himself :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing comma `,` between parameters to `.addClass()`

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            var row = $(this).parent();
            var id = row.data("id");
            console.log("mouseenter", id)
            row.addClass("danger fast");
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var row = $(this).parent();
        var id = row.data("id");
        row.removeClass("danger fast");
        console.log("mouseleave", id)
    }
}, ".sigData"); //pass the element as an argument to .on
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if ($('.sigData').isMouseOver()) {
        var id = $(this).parent().data("id");
        console.log("keydown", id)
        $(this).parent().addClass("danger fast");
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yvr0bdt0/4/

Comment: This will work when the user holds down `ctrl` THEN hovers over. I want the event to be fired when the user is already hovering over the `<td>` and holds down `ctrl`.